# create button in main page to redirect to a response function

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I have  a csv file  in a server. I  have  created a response function to download it in the  users  browser. It work fine. Now  I need   to create a button  in the  main index.html  and create a response  function so  that  file  gets downloaded on clicking it. I just need the download , no redirect to new page required

```
@app.route('/csv/')  
def download_csv(): 
    csv = p
    response = make_response(csv)
    cd = 'attachment; filename=RosterUnified.csv'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = cd 
    response.mimetype='text/csv'

    return response
```

Comment: basically when i click the   button it will  run the   response   funtion mentioned above

Comment: so  the button  in index.html   needs   to be  handled by /csv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing, but if you are simply asking for a button to download the file without making the browser leave the current page:

```
<a href="/csv/" download>Download the file</a>
```

This creates a link which you can style in CSS to appear like a button.
Please tell me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: yes  thanks,  thats  what i meant. Thanks for the   help !!

Comment: when the user  access the   download button from browser, will this   work , or  need to make a  ajax call for this?

Comment: This is simple native html, no AJAX involved.

Comment: I   have   one more challange  now , I   have  "/csv/<p>"   instead   of /csv/ earlier . P is a parameter to the  fuction I need to use. If I put that   in href  will  it  work."/csv/"  was working perfectly for the  button